# If statements aren't functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, null

I am creating a simple website that takes a randomly generated number and based on that number, it will change the text of a paragraph accordingly. I was testing for null values, which was resolved. However, the text is supposed to be capitalized or not based on whether it goes at the beginning or end of the sentence. I cannot seem to resolve this. The link to my jsfiddle is below:

https://jsfiddle.net/MCBlastoise/n2vh40ah/

Also below is my code snippet:

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.button {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #7CFC00;
  cursor: pointer
}
.button-text {
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #9400D3;
  font-size: 76px;
  line-height: 140%;
}
.text {
  color: red;
  font-family: Futura, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
}
#compliment {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, Segoe UI, Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffd400;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.hover {
  width: 108px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 1175px;
  position: absolute;
}
.block-text {
  color: red;
  font-family: Futura, Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Complement.css">
  <title>The Compliment Machine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="heading">The Compliment Machine</h2>
  <p class="text">In the interest of spreading holiday cheer, I have designed this website with one goal in mind. With the assumption that you have already inputted your name, pressing the button below will randomly generate a compliment. Hopefully, this little experiment
    will brighten up your day.</p>
  <div class="button" onclick="inspire()" id="disappear"> <span class="button-text">Click me!</span> 
  </div>
  <br style="line-height:500%">
  <p id="compliment"></p>

  <script>
    var userName = prompt("What is your name?");
    var compliment1 = "Have a nice day";
    var compliment2 = "you contribute to society";
    var compliment3 = "Always be yourself";
    var compliment4 = "you are a wonderful person";
    var compliment5 = "Keep up the good work";
    var compliment6 = "never stop believing in yourself";
    var compliment7 = "you have a great sense of humor";
    var compliment8 = "You should feel proud of yourself";
    var compliment9 = "Never stop trying";
    var compliment10 = "you are a winner";
  </script>

  <script>
    function inspire() {
      var result = Math.random();

      //This code block checks for null, undefined, and other falsy values in the prompt.
      if (userName === null || userName === undefined || userName === "" || !userName) {
        if (0 <= result && result < 0.11) {
          userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.21 <= result && result < 0.31) {
          userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.41 <= result && result < 0.51) {
          userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.71 <= result && result < 0.81) {
          userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.81 <= result && result < 0.91) {
          userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.11 <= result && result < 0.21) {
          userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.31 <= result && result < 0.41) {
          userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.51 <= result && result < 0.61) {
          userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.61 <= result && result < 0.71) {
          userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.91 <= result && result < 1) {
          userName = "Friend";
        }
      }

      //This code block changes the sentence with ID 'compliment' randomly, based on the value of the variable 'result'.
      if (0 <= result && result < 0.11) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment1 + ", " + userName + "!";
      };
      if (0.11 <= result && result < 0.21) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment2 + ".";
      };
      if (0.21 <= result && result < 0.31) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment3 + ", " + userName + ".";
      };
      if (0.31 <= result && result < 0.41) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment4 + ".";
      };
      if (0.41 <= result && result < 0.51) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment5 + ", " + userName + "!";
      };
      if (0.51 <= result && result < 0.61) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment6 + ".";
      };
      if (0.61 <= result && result < 0.71) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment7 + ".";
      };
      if (0.71 <= result && result < 0.81) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment8 + ", " + userName + ".";
      };
      if (0.81 <= result && result < 0.91) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment9 + ", " + userName + ".";
      };
      if (0.91 <= result && result < 1) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment10 + ".";
      };
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not exactly a compliment, but please get familiar with [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays). What comes to the question, hardcode everything in lower case, and use CSS to begin the sentences with a capital.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought about that a little bit ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it actually works, but after one "compliment" `userName` is no longer null or undefined, so your outer if-block won't trigger again. If you want to reassign `userName` each time, you could use a boolean to check if the current `userName` was actually chosen by the user or by your code.

The code could look like this:

```js
var userName = prompt("What is your name?");
//We still use your userName-check, but we store the result in a variable so we can access it everytime the user clicks the button
var generatedUsername = userName === null || userName === undefined || userName === "" || !userName;
var compliment1 = "Have a nice day";
var compliment2 = "you contribute to society";
var compliment3 = "Always be yourself";
var compliment4 = "you are a wonderful person";
var compliment5 = "Keep up the good work";
var compliment6 = "never stop believing in yourself";
var compliment7 = "you have a great sense of humor";
var compliment8 = "You should feel proud of yourself";
var compliment9 = "Never stop trying";
var compliment10 = "you are a winner";


function inspire() {
    var result = Math.random();
    //This code block changes the username if it was chosen by code
    if (generatedUsername) {
        if (0 <= result && result < 0.11) {
            userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.21 <= result && result < 0.31) {
            userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.41 <= result && result < 0.51) {
            userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.71 <= result && result < 0.81) {
            userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.81 <= result && result < 0.91) {
            userName = "friend";
        }
        if (0.11 <= result && result < 0.21) {
            userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.31 <= result && result < 0.41) {
            userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.51 <= result && result < 0.61) {
            userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.61 <= result && result < 0.71) {
            userName = "Friend";
        }
        if (0.91 <= result && result < 1) {
            userName = "Friend";
        }
    }
  
    //This code block changes the sentence with ID 'compliment' randomly, based on the value of the variable 'result'.
    if (0 <= result && result < 0.11) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment1+", "+userName+"!";
    };
    if (0.11 <= result && result < 0.21) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName+", "+compliment2+".";
    };
    if (0.21 <= result && result < 0.31) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment3+", "+userName+".";
    };
    if (0.31 <= result && result < 0.41) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName+", "+compliment4+".";
    };
    if (0.41 <= result && result < 0.51) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment5+", "+userName+"!";
    };
    if (0.51 <= result && result < 0.61) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName+", "+compliment6+".";
    };
    if (0.61 <= result && result < 0.71) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName+", "+compliment7+".";
    };
    if (0.71 <= result && result < 0.81) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment8+", "+userName+".";
    };
    if (0.81 <= result && result < 0.91) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment9+", "+userName+".";
    };
    if (0.91 <= result && result < 1) {
        document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName+", "+compliment10+".";
    };
}
```

Nonetheless, you really should look into simplifying your code, as many segments are repeated over and over again.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, but I'm not really sure how to write that. Could you give me some example code?

Comment: @MCBlastoise Yes, give me like two minutes, I will update my answer ;-)

Comment: @MCBlastoise Done!

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `.toUpperCase()` method to convert your characters to uppercase.

If you want to capitalize the whole word, use:

```
string.toUpperCase()
```

If you want to only capitalize the first letter of the word, use:

```
string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
```

where `string` is the text you want to capitalize.

Comment: Would there be a simple way to change part of the string to uppercase using the `.toUpperCase()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using else if block.

**E.G.:**

```
if (0 <= result && result < 0.11) {
    document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment1 + ", " + userName + "!";
} else if (0.11 <= result && result < 0.21) {
    document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = userName + ", " + compliment2 + ".";
} else if (0.21 <= result && result < 0.31) {
    document.getElementById("compliment").innerHTML = compliment3 + ", " + userName + ".";
};
```

and so on.

Comment: This is of no use here, as this is actually not the problem. Using else-if would yield the same results in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize your name before giving the compliment
i.e

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter(name) {
    return name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
}
```

add

```
userName = capitalizeFirstLetter(userName);
```

before your if conditions where you change the innerHTMLs

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Change name into lowercase first.Then pick up the first character to change into uppercase and replace the first character and get the name with first character as uppercase.

```
var userName = prompt("What is your name?");

var lower = username.toLowerCase();//changes to all characters at lower (because if input is aBcX then it changes to abcx)

var first = username.slice(0,1); //now outputs first character(a in abcx)
var finalname = username.replace(first,first.toUpperCase(first));//outputs Abcx
```